# Calling on the content of an object, and not the name of the object. Or renaming the object the name of the content of said object

Tags: r, names, install.packages, spatialpack

So my goal is to create a function that will first try to load a package. If it cannot be loaded it will then try to install it and then load it. I saw this type of code somewhere and I used it in a couple of my  functions, where I always specified the necessary packages within the functions. I figured this would be a nice tool to generalize into a function. There are so many packages I often forget what I already have installed.

The issue is that in lib and lib2 it passing the name of the object(`"package"`) and not the name of the contents of the object (`"SpatialPack"`). I've tried a few things like specifying the location within the object (`"package[1]"`), but that did nothing.

Any help in getting it to call to the content of the object, and not the name of the object would be awesome. Thanks!

```
  get.package<-function(package){
  lib<-require(package)
  if(lib==TRUE)
  {
    print(paste(c(package,"Package successfully loaded")))
  }
 if(lib==FALSE)
 {
 print(paste(c("Attempting to install and load",package,"Package")))
 install.packages(package)
 lib2<-require(package)
 if (lib2==TRUE)
 {
 print(paste(c(package,"Package successfully installed and loaded")))
 }
 else print(paste(c(package,"Package unable to be installed")))

 }
 }

 get.package("SpatialPack")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `require` and `library` do non-standard evaluation as a convenience, but you can suppress this with a parameter. Try changing your code to:

```
 require(package,  character.only = TRUE)
```

Demonstration:

```
> strangeName <- "sets"
> require(strangeName, character.only=TRUE)
Loading required package: sets

Attaching package: ‘sets’

The following object is masked from ‘package:data.table’:

    set
```